# Authorize a $1.00 charge without collecting

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to figure out a way to authorize a small $1.00 charge for a user but not actually collect/charge the money. Like a pending transaction just to verify that their account is active and has sources to make a payment. Is this possible with PayPal Adaptive Payments? I was running some tests against the sandbox using the `CREATE` `ActionType` for their `Pay` API operation but it seems to return with a success even if the user has <$1.00 in their account

Comment: Failing that, you could charge 3 cents or so and put it in an account that goes to charity or something of that nature. I've seen that in a few systems.

Comment: If there's no way to create a charge like that, is there a way I can verify that a user's PayPal account enrolled in Adaptive Payments can actually pay for something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this is done by charging a few cents and then issuing a refund on validation. The amount is generated randomly and then stored in the database. Once validated, the amount is removed and the verified field is set in a user table.